# Required single SQL query

Tags: sql

I have a table with the name `empdetail` and columns:

```
   Id  Name  Gender
    1  ABC   Male
    2  XYZ   Female
    3  PQR   Male
```

I want to change `Gender` of each emp from `Male` to `Female` and from `Female` to `Male` with single query

Result should be this:

```
1 ABC Female
2 XYZ Male
3 PQR Female
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You Just need to use the **CASE** Statement

```
update <table>
set Gender= case when Gender='Male' then 'Female' 
                 when Gender='Female' then 'Male' 
            end
```

## [SQL fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d4801/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
    select id,name,
           (case when gender='Male'
                     then 'Female'
                 else 'Male' 
            end) as 'Gender' 
    from table
-------------------
   update table set gender=(case when gender='Male'
                     then 'Female' else 'Male' end)
```